# Rails: Adding params to a Devise registration form through radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, controller, devise, radio-button

To enable different roles for users, I added some roles to the *User* model…

```
# class AddRolesToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
   add_column :users, :host, :boolean, :default => false
   add_column :users, :company, :boolean, :default => false
```

and extended the registration form:

```
   <%= radio_button_tag(:role, "host") %>
   <%= label_tag(:role, "Host") %>
   <%= radio_button_tag(:role, "company") %>
   <%= label_tag(:role, "Company") %>
```

Then, in UsersController, i'd like to check for the parameter for *role* (e.g. "host") and mark the boolean field in the record as *true*:

```
  # users_controller.rb  
      if params[:role] == "host"
        params[:user][:host] = true
      elsif params[:role] == "company"
        params[:user][:company] = true
      end
      @user = User.new(params[:user]) …
```

The record won't fetch the new params, what is going wrong? thanks

**EDIT**

So 
there is no *:role* record, just *:host* and *:company* as boolean fields in the db. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've solved this by now, but I think an `attr_accessor` and a `before_validation` function would be the best solution here.

In your `User` model add:

```
attr_accessor :role
before_validation :assign_roles

def assign_roles
  self.host = (role == "host")
  self.company = (role == "company")
end
```

Then you can just add the fields for `:user[:role]` as usual in your view and no extra controller code should be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the name of the radio buttons are set to: user[host]

Instead of radio_button_tag use something like this:

```
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>


    <%= f.radio_button :role, "host" %> Host
    <%= f.radio_button :role, "company" %> Company


    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  <% end %>
```

Add the host and the company fields to the attr_accessible list on the user model like this:

```
attr_accessible :host, :company
```

Comment: `:company` has been added to attr_accessible, `:role` is not a real entry field, i would only use its param to fill the respective fields  "host" or "company" as true. Unfortunately it does not work (even if i put :role to attr)

Comment: Thanks, but `f.radio_button :role` depends on a real :role record for the user. I only have boolean fields for :host and :company.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to put the conditionals into the user model? How would i fetch the params in there?

Comment: You have to pass the params as an argument to the model function. Otherwise you cannot access the params directly inside models.

Comment: Thanks, could you provide an example argument?